# How to Convert the Simple Integer Key of a Kafka Stream to a Complex Avro Type Key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a streaming app topology which consumes from a simple topic with an Integer key and an AVRO body. I would like to manipulate the stream and write to a topic with a complex AVRO key. But I can't find the the "key" equivalent to mapValues(). In other words, I seem to be stuck with the original Integer key. Can I convert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "equivalent" is just `map()`. You would return the value in the KeyValuePair type as unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

I just found what I needed: selectKey((k, v) -> newKey)

```
    kstream.selectKey((k, v) -> AvroObjBuiltFromAvsc.newBuilder().setValue("abc").build())
.to("topic_with_avro_key");
```